# PWA advice needed regarding large number of static assets

Tags: reactjs, svg, audio

I am a building a educational app that has around 1100 SVGs. They very small per svg like 800bytes. I am quite new to reactjs.

For each SVG I have an audio.

Therefore

- 1100 svgs
- 1100 audio clips

I am using create-react-app.

Intend using howlerJS to ensure audio files are cached.

Also lazy load the svgs.

Does create-react-app cache the svgs?

Should I change my approach? Maybe merge svgs into a sprite..

Should I merge mp3s and play parts of the audio as needed..

My main thing is that audio and svgs get installed when user installs PWA.

Any feedback will be appreciated

Comment: What is the average and total size of your audio clips?

Comment: @AlexUnder 10KB

Comment: Is that average per clip or total size?

Comment: @AlexUnder per clip. Total we still working on it. But x1000 .images are around 3MB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no magic bullet to your problem, but here are some key points to consider:

- It won't take long for you to make a request and get a response for each and every pair of svg/audio that user selects (on demand, not 1100 altogether).
- Not knowing your app's logic and UX, I can extrapolate that loading 3MB of SVG and 10MB of audio will be more noticeable, than waiting for on-demand request/response of 11KB.
- As a background job, try to load as many files to upfront as you can, while there are no running requests from user.
- Cache everything that was already loaded to avoid repeated requests
- Try to optimize your sources in the first place, since minimal changes to an individual file will lead to a major impact on scale of x1000. A good place to start is checking your floating point in SVG: try to avoid something like `<path d="M33.6286316,13.9605932...` and keep it as simple as your precision allows you to. In most cases `<path d="M33.62,13.96...` will do the job.